# Tableau Duplicate Marks card values

Tags: filter, tableau-api

I am not sure why but in funnel chart in Tableau the marks card duplicated the users counts that are displayed

[Screenshot of my Funnel Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YU4mL.png)

I have tried filtering out the user count from the marks value but I still have the same problem